# iframe links with internal targets - working in Chrome and Firefox, NOT IE?

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, iframe, facebook-iframe

I am creating a Custom Facebook Fan Page using iframes and it's working great in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox but not working in Internet Explorer.  Is there a quick easy way to work around this issue.

```
<div id="nav">
  <font id="fnav">
    <center>
      <a href="http://bit.ly/MSC-Home" target="internal">HOME</a> | 
      <a href="http://bit.ly/MSC-Schedule" target="internal">SCHEDULE</a> | 
      <a href="http://bit.ly/MSC-Music" target="internal">MUSIC</a> | 
      <a href="http://bit.ly/MSC-Tickets" target="internal">TICKETS</a>
    </center>
  </font>
</div>

<iframe id="box" src="http://bit.ly/MSC-Home" name="internal">&nbsp;</iframe>
```

You can check out the working example at http://www.facebook.com/pages/GTD/104839016256119?sk=app_168848466497060

Answer (score 0):

how about the width and height tags?

```
<iframe id="box" src="http://bit.ly/MSC-Home" name="internal" width="450" height="650">&nbsp;</iframe>
```

Comment: I have the width & height in the "box" id

Comment: What do you mean by in the "box" ID? ID is a separate attribute from width and height. Do you have it specified in CSS somewhere?